# CSS DRY button states

Tags: css

Is there a way to do this this as its just repeating the same code?

```
.button-hover {
  color:                           $button-hover-font-color;
  background-color:                $button-hover-color;
  &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &:visited {
    color:                           $button-hover-font-color;
    background-color:                $button-hover-color;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can just delete the `&:hover, &:focus, &:active, &:visited` section. Won't the colors apply for those states as well as long as the class is on the element?

Comment: like @jbabey said use the cascade!

Comment: Casade didn't work as once you hover or press the button goes to it's default states.

Comment: @jbabey This does not work if you have specified a global hover state before either using `:link:hover` or `a:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, try plain CSS syntax:

```
.button-hover, .button-hover:hover, .button-hover:focus, .button-hover:active, .button-hover:visited {
    color:            $button-hover-font-color;
    background-color: $button-hover-color;
}
```

Or use a mixin: (I only know LESS syntax, but I guess it's similar for whatever preprocessor you are using)

```
.button-hover {
    color:            @button-hover-font-color;
    background-color: @button-hover-color;

    &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &:visited {
        .button-hover();
    }
}
```